# How to write Chinese characters to file

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, character-encoding

I use this code to write some Chinese characters to a file:

```
String str = "询问需求";
byte[] byteArray = str.getBytes("UTF-8");
FileOutputStream fous = new FileOutputStream(f);
fous.write(byteArray);
fous.close();
```

Result afterwards is `è¯¢é—®éœ€æ±‚`. Whats the problem with this?

Comment: This isn't a Chinese font. It is a Chinese *character set.* what did you read the file with?

Comment: Looks like you're compiling/running with an incorrect encoding. Can you give more details about it?

Answer (score 0):

When writing textual data, use a writer, and specify the encoding to use. Always, no exception.

So in your case:

```
Writer out =  new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file), "utf-8");
out.write(str);
out.close();
```

Also, obviously, make sure that your source code is properly encoded. If you save it in UTF-16 but let javac default to UTF-8, for example, then the content of your string will not be what you think it is.

Finally, when opening the content of your file with an external editor, make sure it knows what encoding the file was written in. If it opens an UTF-8 encoded file assuming it's MacRoman, it'll not display it properly.

Comment: Not that in this context, you can replace my use of *encoding* with @EJP's *character set*. I believe his is the correct term.

Comment: I tried Nicolas Rinaudo, it still results same "è¯¢é?®é??æ±?"

Comment: In order for us to be able to help you, you need to give us more information than "it does not work". For example, since your issue is clearly one of character set, if you do not tell us what character set you're using to write the data, nor the one you're using to read it, then with all the goodwill in the world, there is precisely nothing we can do.